# Set screen resolution of a gitlab image for UI tests

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a python selenium test framework that opens browsers and runs UI tests as part of gitlab CI.

However, the screen resolution of the host seems to be:  1360x1020 according to: http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/ when it runs. I'm hoping to increase it to 1920x1080 so UI tests run at a typical desktop resolution.

Is it possible to set the screen resolution where the browser runs?

`image: python:3.11

test:
stage: test-automation
services:
- name: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
script:
- apt-get update
- apt-get install -y x11-xserver-utils
- xrandr | grep '*' | awk '{print $1}'   #error "Can't open display"
- #python selenium project running on the chrome service above`

I've tried using xrandr (as in the code) but looks like that doesn't have access to the display.